# Why do I get a missing handler for logger "sentry.errors"?

Tags: django, sentry

I installed `django-sentry` in an integrated fashion.
I then ran `python manage.py shell` and tried to log like this:

```
>> import logging
>> mylog = logging.getLogger('sentrylogger')
>> mylog.handlers
[<logging.StreamHandler instance at 0x9f6130c>,
 <sentry.client.handlers.SentryHandler instance at 0x9ffed4c>]

>> mylog.debug('this is a test 1')
DEBUG 2011-09-28 11:10:33,178 <ipython console> 4607 -1217300800 this is a test 1
No handlers could be found for logger "sentry.errors"
```

Currently, nothing is written to the sentry. I believe the missing logger 'sentry.errors' is the root cause of my inability to log to sentry. Am I on the right track ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a handler missing. I cannot explain why logging to one log should affect another log instance, but maybe if you try to write this before doing mylog.debug(..) it will work:

```
sentry_errors_log = logging.getLogger("sentry.errors")
sentry_errors_log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Furthermore, refer to the documentation about older versions that seem to add sentry.errors log handler manually:

http://readthedocs.org/docs/sentry/en/latest/config/index.html#older-versions

Answer (score 1):

if you are running sentry on your own domain with HTTPS, there is a bug in sentry SNI support. check https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/523 for more details. A quick workaround is to replace DSN scheme by `threaded+requests+https`:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'threaded+requests+https://xxxxxxxxxxxx@sentry.example.com/1',
}
```

Comment: Helpful answer for when the underlying error discovered by adding a sentry error handler is SSL related.